No cheap NC tactile switch on the market?
I have been struggling with a problem that seems so simple I am a bit ashamed raising it here.
1 — Context
I have designed a PCB that plays a chiptune song when powered. What I wanted to do a minimal hardware modification to add a “next” button without any major change to the PCB (the design has already been done, updating it would be too expensive for my project). I am using an ATtiny1616 chip and all the gpios are already used for the speaker and LEDs (PA0, which is the possible reset pin, is connected to a LED). I also want to keep the unit hardware cost as low as possible.
2 — Solution considered
Since all the pins are used (to keep the unit cost low I don't want to add a shift register to free some pins), the way I consider doing this is by adding a button forcing a restart. I will also update the software (easier to change than redesigning the PCB): at the start of the program (but after some delay to ensure power is stable enough) I will increment a counter in the EEPROM so that each time the chip start, it plays a different tune. Then pressing the button would act as a “next” button.
3 — Options
I see 3 main options to do this in a way my unit cost increase by a few cents maximum:

A — Finding a “normally closed” on the VCC line. I can find lots of 1 cent SMD normally open switches (on Mouser, JLCPCB, or LCSC), but the cheapest “normally closed” are .50 cents which is too expensive for my target price per unit. Did I get something wrong or search with a wrong name (“NC tactile switch” and a couple of similar alternatives) ?

B — Using a NO switch (1 cent) and a transistor (4 cents) and a resistor. I seem a bit complex — is this what is usually done in SMD design when a “NC switch” function is needed ?

C — Using the ATtiny1616 Reset pin. Since this pin is already connected to a LED, how can I ensure nothing bad (short circuit) happens if reset is pressed while the ATtiny powers the LED?


4 — Questions

A : I can't believe NC switches are 50 times more expensive than NO ones. Any idea or reference?

B : Is this solution “state of the art” design ?

C : how to avoid a short circuit if I try to drive the pin liw when it is outputting a high value ?



Joe Cohen - Hi, When you asked your previous question, it appeared to be an off-topic shopping-type question and was "closed" for that reason. A short while ago, you edited it into more of an engineering question (good!) - but instead of waiting for that edited version to be reviewed & considered for reopening, which is the correct process here, you've reposted that version as this new question. That breaks the primary quality control mechanism of the site. Please don't do that again :) || Since this question has been answered, I have deleted that previous question.

There are lots of tricks to make the most of a limited number of IO pins, especially with LEDs and switches. A schematic of your existing design would be helpful.

I'm curious about how the LED is connected to the reset line. Using reset seems to be a good approach, and could potentially employ a normally-open switch, but we would need a schematic showing us the circuitry associated with he reset line.

Sorry for reposting this - I initially edited the original question but as it was still marked as closed I thought I had to repose it - thanks for the help !

Sorry I can't post the schematic now (it is being redesigned). But the idea of designing the led connected to the reset pin differently (to vcc through a resistor and to the pin so that "low" lights it) look a good idea.

A. That's the way it is, for technical and market reasons. There are plenty of inexpensive pushbutton switches that are made more like key
switches and have N.C. contacts (eg. DPDT). But they are not called 'tact' switches and tend to be larger. You need to look at the suppliers if that sort of thing would work. There are also tiny 'sensor' switches made for use in mechanisms- some of which may be N.C.
B. It's a way to do it. Could hardly be any simpler.
C. Set the pin to be open-drain. You may have issues getting the logic levels you need.

Thanks - very clear. But I would have to design designing the led connected to the reset pin differently (to vcc through a resistor and to the pin so that "low" lights it look a good idea), right ?

A: Off-topic really, becuse you are asking for parts what to buy and from where. If NC switches are more expensive than NO switches, then use NO switches and maybe add other parts which is still cheaper than a NC switch.
B: Depends. If you want a cheap solution, the cheapest solution might even be to design in a larger MCU with enough IO pins than to make a more complex and expensive circuitry around it.
C: a simple resistor. You can drive the LED state for 99% of the time, and set the pin as input for 1% of the time to read the state.
Also each time you erase and write the EEPROM with the counter update, it wears down a bit. It might handle thousands of erase/write cycles though, but sometimes bytes are grouped so each time you write a single byte, e.g four neighbouring bytes are updated, so writing 4 bytes means all four bytes see four erase and write operations.

Akso, not sure I will find cheaper than attiny1616 with 16k flash (padauk chips are cheaper but with a small flash).

My counter will be one bytes and I have read EEPROM accept 100.000 to 1000000 writing cycles - this is much more than I need.
